# Wireless Printing from Ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, printing, wireless

Would someone be able to help me out with how I can add a print option to my ipad app which allows me to print wirelessly? it would be great if someone could post a tutorial link for that...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to present your documents in a [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) - the resulting action menu gives you the print option for 'free'

Comment: thank you for the reply.. I will check it out.. would you be able to give me a simple example on how to do it?

Comment: @ roger.. would you also be able to tell me how this is different from Airprint or is it the same one?